# What is fullform of RTU in modbusRTU?

Tags: modbus

I am using modbusRTU. But Did not found fullform for 'RTU'. Is it some random name? or it have some meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTU likely stands for Remote Terminal Unit.

Differences between Modbus RTU and Modbus ASCII are explained [here](http://www.simplymodbus.ca/ASCII.htm).